# spread operator does not set the value to state properly

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a weird issue when trying to set my state in my reducer.

I have the following:

```
state = {
  ...state,
  activeChannel: action.payload.channelList[0].name
    .replace("&", "and")
    .replace("`", "")
    .replace("'", "")
    .replace("-", "")
    .replace(/\s/g, "")
    .toLowerCase(),
  preferedChannelsList: channelObjectTemp
};
```

When I console.log the state I can see that preferedChannelsList has been set correctly but activeChannel is not there.

When I remove the ...state the I can see activeChannel set in state.
Is there anything wrong with the way I use spread operator?

Update : more of the code in reducer

```
    switch (action.type) {
      case GET_CHANNEL:
        let totalNumberOfStories=0;
        let activeChannelList=action.payload.channelList.slice(0,lazyLoadingStep);
        let channelObjectTemp= {
            ...state.preferedChannelsList,
           [action.payload.channelList[0].name.replace("&","and").replace("`","").replace("'","").replace('-','').replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase()]:action.payload.channelList[0]};


        state={...state,activeChannel: action.payload.channelList[0].name.replace("&","and").replace("`","").replace("'","").replace('-','').replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase(),
            "preferedChannelsList":channelObjectTemp };
        break;
```

Comment: can you show more of your reducer?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Please see the update

Comment: you are not returning anything from the reducer. instead of `state={...state ...` do ```return {...state, ...```

This may not fix it though

Comment: @Beaulne This is not a full code I return at the end of switch. For sake of more clarity I just paste the part causing issue

Comment: Can you post the entire code? also it seems like you are mutating the state, which is bad practice. you should never reassign state, but return a new value

Comment: a reducer should look similar to

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "action":
      return {
        ...state
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```